# mysql select from multiple tables even if one does not contain where clause

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have two (or three, or four...) tables which i want to select all at once to count the number of entries in all tables together.

for example if i have some tables:
'news', 'articles', 'galleries'

in every table i have a row called like "author_id"

now, if i use following select statement:

```
SELECT *
FROM
news as n, articles as a, galleries as g
WHERE
n.author = 1
AND a.user = 1
AND g.uploader = 1
```

i only get a result if every table has at least one row with a author (or user or uploader whatever) matching '1'
how can i get a result even if one (or two..) tables do not contain '1'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, you can combine the results of all table using `UNION ALL` in a subquery. Then you can now `COUNT()` the specified `Author_ID`. The following query will get the total number of records of a specified `author_id` in ALL tables.

```
SELECT COUNT(author_ID)
FROM
(
    SELECT userID AS Author_ID FROM news
    UNION ALL
    SELECT user_ID AS Author_ID FROM articles
    UNION ALL
    SELECT UiD AS Author_ID FROM galleries
) a
WHERE a.Author_ID = 1
```

followup question,

- how do you want the results to be shown? because this can also be solved by joining the tables.
- or what is the main table and the referencing table where you want to count the records?

Comment: think of something like your user profile. i just want to count something like "user John Woo submitted 4200 replies." The problem is that i dont have a table called replies. a reply could be something like this comment, which would be stored in a table called "comments" or a reply could be something like your reply..which would be stored in a table called "replies"..so there isn't really a "main table"..all tables which i want to select are independent from another..
and i can't use your Select because the row which stores my userid isn't called author_id in every table..

Comment: ok of course..this will work.
actually i wanted to avoid union select because wouldn't this be perform like three single selects?

Comment: @aeres I get it, see my updated answer, so the problem is the column names of the tables can be different from each other. You can add an `alias` on each columns.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use the fields to display from every table like

```
SELECT n.author, a.user, g.uploader FROM news as n, articles as a, galleries as g
WHERE n.author = 1 AND a.user = 1 AND g.uploader = 1
```

then it will works

Comment: if i use your statement it won't return anything if e.g. galleries hasn't a row with the value g.uploader = "1". its actually the same thing i wrote in my question..

Comment: as in the above query you used uploader is the field name g.uploader means galleries.uploader

Answer (score 0):

Your `news` table seems to be the parent table and so you should `LEFT JOIN` the `articles` and `galleries` table with `news` table to get the count of authors, as follows:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    news n
    LEFT JOIN articles a
    ON n.author_id = a.author_id AND a.user = 1
    LEFT JOIN galleries g
    ON n.author_id = g.authori_id AND g.uploader = 1
```

Comment: theres no parent table. all tables are independent from each other.